# Non-editable fields in word table after export from Power Bi paginated report

Tags: mysql, powerbi, word-addins, power-bi-report-server

I need to create a power bi paginated report whose source is mysql. This paginated report should give an export option in word file but Some columns of exported word file should be non-editable. later this word file needs to be converted to Excel file which will loaded back to mysql db.

my concern is non-editable fields in word file. Is this Possible?